# hazelcast Configuration for two Jboss instances in same physical machine

Tags: hazelcast

I am trying to use hazelcast for caching. We have two applications running on two jboss 7.1 instances in the same physical machines. Both the applications are running in different ports.

Below is my code for starting a server node.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
     HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = CacheHelper.getCacheInstance();
     Map<Long, String> cache = hazelcastInstance.getMap("data");

     Long inputKey = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("inputKey"));
     String inputMsg = request.getParameter("inputMsg");

     StringBuffer mainStr = null;

     if(null != inputMsg && !(inputMsg.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))){
        if(null!=inputKey && inputKey != 0 && cache.containsKey(inputKey)) {
            mainStr = new StringBuffer(cache.get(inputKey));
            mainStr.append(inputMsg);
        } else {
            mainStr = new StringBuffer(inputMsg);
        }

        cache.put(inputKey,mainStr.toString());
    }
}
```

Every time I am getting a new cache.

Is my understanding correct we just need to create two server nodes. It will automatically discover the other nodes. It doesn't require any kind of XML configuration.

Thanks,
Biswa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Biswa,

```
     HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
```

This line creates a new Hazelcast instance every time your `doGet` method called. You need to create Hazelcast instance only once, then use it to access distributed objects. I believe `CacheHelper.getCacheInstance()` method does that.

For the second question, yes, by default Hazelcast nodes discover other members
via multicast, so no config needed.

Please make sure that you have only one  `Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance()` call in each app & you use that instance to access dist.objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Once I created a singleton object, caching is working fine. I have a followup query on this. Is there any way we can use disk storage in case our cache data grows.

Comment: Hazelcast Enterprise has a Hot-Restart solution. It copies the map data to disk but don't touch the in-memory data. It's for starting your member faster with the same data before you shutdown it. It's a commercial feature. You can request a trial Enterprise HD license & test it.

Comment: You also have an option to link your Map to a backing storage, like a database. This way, when a key not found, Hazelcast will call your implementation to load the data from database & store it when you update the data, if you want. By defining a TTL & size, you can make sure that you have a certain amount of data in the memory. And by MapLoader/MapStore, you can load the data from a 3rd party data-store if not found in Hazelcast. This is an open-source feature. Please see related doc:http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.3/manual/html-single/index.html#loading-and-storing-persistent-data

Comment: Thanks for your help. I opted for database storage.